# Incorrect syntax near 'WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER'. C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-2016

I have a sql query like this

SELECT * FROM vm.tablename WHERE DeviceId = 3 FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;

I am trying to execute this sql query from c# application like this

```
  using (var dataContext = new DataContext(_connectionString)){
    var query = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM vm.tablename");
            query.Append(" WHERE DeviceId = ");    
            query.Append(deviceId);
            query.Append("FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER");
             Debug.WriteLine(query);
    List<string> = dataContext.ExecuteQuery<string>(query.ToString()).ToList();
    }
```

I am getting an exception on the line  ExecuteQuery :'Incorrect syntax near 'WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER'.'.
In output window i get the query like this :'SELECT * FROM vm.tablename WHERE DeviceId = 3 FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER' which works fine when i run it in the sql server mgmt studio but, it gives exception when i run c# code.

Comment: On what database are you running?

Comment: Make sure you are using SQL Server 2016, because that's a new feature available in that version (or newer).

Comment: You are missing a space between the value of `deviceId` and `FOR`

Comment: @PatrickHofman SQL server 2016

Comment: also be sure deviceId has the expected value type.

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn about parameterized SQL, too...

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden Did that, it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because this:

```
new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM vm.tablename");
            query.Append(" WHERE DeviceId = ");    
            query.Append(deviceId);
            query.Append("FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER");
```

results in this:

```
SELECT * FROM vm.tablename WHERE DeviceId = :deviceIDFOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Put an additional space before "FOR" in your last line.   I suggest making a custom `QueryBuilder` class with methods that accept strings and resolve spacing and "." notation for you, it saves a lot of trouble with dynamic SQL.

Comment: i have done that and my query looks like this "SELECT * FROM vm.tablename WHERE DeviceId = 3 FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER".. still error persists

Comment: Is the *database* returning the error or is it the `SqlDataReader/Adapter` itself returning the error?

Comment: This can occur if you accidentally use the wrong overload to construct either of those objects.  Please add your DataReader/Adapter declaration and initialization code to your original post.